# How to switchMap a stream of 3 Observables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs

I have to combine 3 streams of Observable into one.
I'm using Angular and Firebase, here is how this is suppose to work...

Step 1: I send a query to Firebase and receive an `array`. I will use the **id** from a specific property to query something else for the *Step 2*.

Step 2: I use the **ID** from *Step 1* to get data from another collection, for this I'll receive another `array`. In this array, I have another **ID** that I need for *Step 3*.

Step 3: I need to get an object from the database using the **ID** provided on Step2.

In order to get this working, I'm using `switchMap()` but the problem is that I'm getting `VOID` as result of the method.

Help please!

**UPDATE:** I changed the original code. With this one I can see the `console.log` but when I subscribe, I get nothing.

```
getPanic() {
  this.panicInfo = this.panicService.getPanic(this.checkID)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(panicSnaps => {
        const requests = panicSnaps.map(panicSnap => {
          const panicObj = {id: panicSnap.payload.doc.id, ...panicSnap.payload.doc.data() as any};
          return this.panicService.getActions(panicObj.id)
            .pipe(
              tap({ complete: () => console.log('completed')}),
              map(data => {
                panicObj.actions = data;
                console.log(panicObj);
                return panicObj;
              })
            );
        });
        return forkJoin(requests);
      }),
    )
    .subscribe();
}
```

Comment: firebase provides a stream of data, not single emission observables, are you looking for a stream or a one time observable?

Comment: One time Observable works as well.

Answer (score 0):

it's a good idea to break streams up so you can see where you're going wrong.

```
getActionUsers(actionSnaps) {
  const actions = actionSnaps.map(actionSnap => {
    const actionsObj: PanicActions = {...actionSnap};
    // need to return inside map
    return this.userService.getUser(actionsObj.executor).pipe( 
      map(userSNAP => ({...actionsObj, ...userSNAP})) // combine only action and user here
    );
  });
  // need to combine and return (deal with empty)
  return actions.length ? combineLatest(...actions) : of([]);
}

getPanicActions(panicData) {
  const panic = panicData.map(snaps => {
    const panicObj: Panic = {...snaps.payload.doc.data()};
    return this.panicService.getActions(panicObj.id).pipe(
      switchMap(actionSnaps => this.getActionUsers(actionSnaps).pipe(
        map(res => ({...panicObj, ...res})) // add panicObj here
      ))
    );
  });
  // forkJoin only works on observables that complete, use combineLatest when they don't, also need to deal with empty
  return panic.length ? combineLatest(...panic) : of([]);
}


getPanic() {
  this.panicService.getPanic(this.checkID).pipe( 
    switchMap(panicData => this.getPanicActions(panicData))
  ).subscribe(data => {
    // The panicInfo is of type 'Panic' but I get a TS Lint error that says:
    // Type 'void[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Panic': id, checkId, city, geolocation, and 10 more
    this.panicInfo = data;
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey @bryan60 thanks but still didn't work. :( I no longer get the type error from before, but I get nothing. I tried console.log and nothing happens.

Comment: that suggests one of your inner streams is not emitting or you haven't switched to combineLatest

Comment: Is there a way to test that?

Comment: add logging into the streams with tap. see if any aren't emitting

Comment: Hey @bryan60 I tried nothing :( I added `tap({ complete: () => console.log('completed')})` no logs

Comment: as i said before, firebase observables never complete unless you complete them with an operator of some kind, which is why `forkJoin` won't work for you.  so logging in "complete" will not be helpful for you. just use normal `tap(d => console.log(d))` and put it at key points in your stream. make sure you get an action list for every panicObj and a user for every actionObj

Comment: also, can either actions or users be an empty list? that would create problems... i edited my answer to handle empty lists appropriately

Comment: Hey @bryan60 thank you for your help bud. This time I got the object from the getPanic(), but still nothing from the actions or users. Sorry switchMap is still something that I don't fully get.

Comment: I can’t debug from here. You need to add logging or put together a blitz.

Comment: Hey @brian60 I'll do that. Thanks bud

Answer (score 0):

test this code:

```
getPanic() {
  this.panicService.getPanic(this.checkID)
    .pipe(
      switchMap((panicData: any[]) => forkJoin(
        ...panicData.map(snaps => {
          const panicObj = { ...snaps.payload.doc.data() };

          return this.panicService.getActions(panicObj.id).pipe(
            switchMap((actionSnaps: any[]) => forkJoin(
              ...actionSnaps.map(actionSnap => {
                const actionsObj: any = { ...actionSnap };

                return this.userService.getUser(actionsObj.executor).pipe(
                  map(userSNAP => ({ ...panicObj, ...actionsObj, ...userSNAP })),
                );
              }),
            )),
          );
        }),
      )),
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
      // The panicInfo is of type 'Panic' but I get a TS Lint error that says:
      // Type 'void[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Panic': id, checkId, city, geolocation, and 10 more
      this.panicInfo = data;
    });
```

my example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-u2qezl)

I do not know what data you receive in requests.

Comment: give me data for answer requests

Comment: Hey @Chrus I've changed the code. I can see now the console.log inside the switchmap but when I subscribe I get nothing.

Comment: Hey, where exactly, add in stackblitz

Comment: Hey @Chris I can't save on Stackblitz, it doesn't allow me. But here it is on gist. https://gist.github.com/iconio/920dd4cf97852618061f833b6e237be3

Comment: change this line `return forkJoin(requests);` in this `return forkJoin(... requests);`

Comment: I did, no dice :( I'm starting to panic... The console.log on line 12 works perfectly. It mounts the object exactly like it should, but it feels like it dies there.

Comment: give me the answer from this request this.panicService.getPanic(this.checkID)

Comment: and for this this.panicService.getActions(panicObj.id)

Comment: I've put the response on the Gist, it's better to see the formatting.

Comment: give the data in the console.log https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-hztgqw

Comment: It's a big object. Here is a screenshot. I noticed that the first part you're getting the snapshot from Firebase which doesn't contain the payload. Just an observation. :D https://i.postimg.cc/9FVJNWbG/screenshot.jpg

Comment: add this to see if you have any errors return forkJoin(...requests).pipe(catchError(error => of(error));

Comment: and this .subscribe(console.log);

Comment: Hey Chris I did and still nothing :/ I get both steps2 but nothing other than that.

Comment: if you want I can help you somewhere in a chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211910/discussion-between-iconio-and-chris).